# Add color to part of a mesh or OBJ Qt3D 5.9 in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

In Qt3D 5.9, I am using scene 3D to render an .obj file and display it. I also have enabled object picking, so when a user selects part of the object, I know exactly where on the model they clicked. What I would like to do is add color to that part of the obj/mesh that the user clicked on. To be more specific, for the 'y' value that the user clicked on, I want to color a line all the way around the object model on that 'y' value. I've looked around online and can't find anything to help. Unfortunately I'm not familiar when it comes to 3D objects, meshes, etc. How can I color just part of a mesh in Qt 3D 5.9?

Answer (score 0):

Since you managed to load your own meshes, I suppose you understood how the GeometryRenderer and Geometry QML Components work. The Geometry component takes attribute that define (for instance) the position and normals of your object. The names you give to these attributes allow you to retrieve them in custom shaders. You can add an Attribute in your geometry that defines a buffer in which you will store vertices colors instead of positions and normals.

Then, you will need a custom Material (If you haven't a custom Material, try to read the QML doc to understand how it works. I know, the doc is not really complete but it is a good start)

This custom material will allow you to call your own shader, in which you can retrieve the color of a vertex in the same way you retrieve it's position.

So to conclude, since you want to color just a part of the vertices, you will need

- A buffer containing all the colors of all vertices of your mesh
- A Geometry attribute that tells how to read this buffer
- A script that update the buffer on selection
- A custom material and a custom shader that uses the color buffer to paint the object

This is a not-so-easy thing to accomplish, but it is possible and should give you a better undestanding of how Geometry, Materials and shaders work in QML.

If you are not familiar with these, I would suggest that you first put asside the par vertex color buffer and try to make a custom shader that paint all your object red. From that you will be able to go on and find out how to pass per vertex colors to your shader

Good luck